# Почему в OpenGL вращение объекта не ускоряется со временем?

Tags: c++, opengl

Не мог бы кто-нибудь помочь разобраться с вращением объекта с помощью:

```
glm::mat4 transform(1.0f);
transform = glm::rotate(transform, (float)glfwGetTime(), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));
```

https://ravesli.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/04/39.gif
Почему получается такое плавное вращение ,то есть вращение не ускоряется,хотя таймер увеличивается(т.е значения угла тоже должно увеличиваться) и видно ,что "скорость" одинаковая.Если,допустим, прошло 70 с,то угол уже должен быть 70,но вращение тоже самое(скорость не увеличивается/уменьшается).

Comment: Ну так время же монотонно растет, вот и угол поворота монотонно изменяется. Чтобы ускорялось, надо что-то типа `угол = время_от_старта ^ 2` например. Или матрицу поворота не пересоздавать, а каждый раз "доповорачивать".

Comment: @Kromster я вот этого и не понимаю.То есть если она пересоздаётся,то как происходит:допустим,на предыдущей итерации время было 42,то картинка повернется из начального положения на 43 или от предыдущей картинки на 43?Просто я понимал так,что если таймер 43,то от предыдущего положения картинка поворачивается на 43,но по анимации видно,что она постоянно поворачивается на одинаковый угол.

Comment: **Каждый кадр у вас заново** берется картинка повернутая на 0 градусов и вы ее поворачиваете на столько градусов, сколько сейчас времени (прям как секундную стрелку). Вы же нигде не храните состоя ния прошлого кадра.

Comment: @Kromster большое спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Перенесу в ответ, т.к. их чаще, чем комментарии читают

Answer (score 0):

Ну так время же монотонно растет, вот и угол поворота монотонно изменяется. Чтобы ускорялось, надо что-то типа угол = время_от_старта ^ 2 например. Или матрицу поворота не пересоздавать, а каждый раз "доповорачивать".

**Каждый кадр у вас заново** берется картинка повернутая на 0 градусов и вы ее поворачиваете на столько градусов, сколько сейчас времени (прям как секундную стрелку). Вы же нигде не храните состояние прошлого кадра.